# How to represent data with large differences in scale?

Tags: data-visualization, scales

For my paper, I want to present my results for two websites, with and without delays, I then go onto optimise that website. For example, normal website with and without optimisations and then optimised website with and without delay. Separating into two different graph is not ideal as it may be misleading, and if I keep the scales the same, it is not visible. I think it would not be best to skip values/data as well, as it may be misleading. Any ideas what I should do?

Here is with normal scale and with log scale.
[image]
[image]